# show json data in index file

Tags: json, node.js, express, fs

I dont understand why I cant display my json data. I am new to javascript and I want to display the data in the json file to my index file.

I have used the express generator for all the files. I did read that I should add this FS code in my app.js, but I cant use the data variable in my index file in my view. Any help ?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var file = __dirname + '/public/list/list.json';
  var data;
  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(data);
  });

  res.render('index', { title: data });

  console.log(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

here is my json file

```
{
         "username":"xyz",
         "password":"xyz@123",
         "email":"xyz@xyz.com",
         "uid": 1100
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fs.readFile is asynchronous , so you should put res.render(..) inside his callback , because it will fired when the readFile function ends. So change your code to :

```
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    res.render('index', { title: data });
});
```

Comment: Okej, that did work and is it best practise to have it read the json file in the routing or in the app.js file ?

Comment: as SlashmanX said , depends on your case , if your json  never change then require it because it will be cached , in the other case if your json change dynamically you could use solution above.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but there's also an alternative.

If you're using this file for your index page, it'd be used a lot. If the data isn't changing, you can simply `require` the JSON file at the top of your code and return it in the request.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var list = require(__dirname + '/public/list/list.json');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', { title: list });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, if that data does change frequently, reading the file is the way to go.